# Backwards Fibonacci Sequence in Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, fibonacci

Does anyone know how to output the Fibonacci sequence backwards based on a given Fibonacci number as a starting value? I'm using the MIPS r3000 processor.

Comment: Some restrictions on input numbers that the resulting program must conform to might come in useful.

Comment: What part is causing you problems? Generate the numbers forward in memory until you hit the starting point then simply print them backwards.

Comment: calculate the series (up to the given number), and push each element onto the stack. once finished, pop and display each pushed value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MIPS Recursive Fibonacci Sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976456/mips-recursive-fibonacci-sequence)